# En que me estoy equivocando con este codigo en mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: Este es el codigo]

[image: Este es el error]

Hola soy estudiante de 2º de ASIR y tengo un ejercicio de creacion de tablas, insercion de datos y consultas que debo entregar en breve y me he quedado estancado por mas que lo reviso no doy con el problema.
agradezco cualquier ayuda.

El error me da al crear la segunda tabla.
Me dice que no existe la columna NumDpto pero es que es una clave foránea no tiene que existir en la misma tabla(Empleados sino en Departamentos)
Muchas gracias saludos.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no tiene que existir en la misma tabla?

Comment: Por cierto, sería ideal si pusieras el código en modo texto, es más fácil de leer y las imágenes no son siempre visibles para todos. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).

Comment: Esto parece un error de concepto: las claves foráneas no son creadas automáticamente por MySQL, debes definir el campo en la tabla y luego crear la relación como clave foránea.

Comment: Digo que al ser una clave foranea el campo relacionado no tiene por que llamarse igual, el campo relacionado con la clave principal de la primera tabla (Numdpto) lo declaro como NDep en la segunda tabla

Comment: /home/adal/Empresa2ADSACA.sql

Comment: El error está en el `INDEX`, como bien ha apuntado @JDev, allí usas una columnas que no existe en la tabla.

Answer (score 6):

Tu problema está en el index de la tabla Empleados no en la FK. No es NumDpto si no NDep

Cambialo por

```
index (NDep)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código debería quedar del modo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE Departamentos(
    NumDpeto INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NomDepto VARCHAR(30),
    Localizacion VARCHAR(30)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Empleados(
    NEmp INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NomEmp VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Empleo VARCHAR(30),
    FechaCont DATE,
    Supvs INT,
    Salario INT,
    Ndep INT,
    Comis INT,
    NumDepto INT NOT NULL,
    INDEX(Ndep),
    CONSTRAINT fk_empleado_depto FOREIGN KEY(NumDepto) REFERENCES Departamentos(NumDpeto)
)ENGINE=INNODB; 


CREATE TABLE GradoSal(
    Grado INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SalarioMin INT NOT NULL,
    SalarioMax INT NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Lo que hice fue:

1. en la segunda tabla, llamada `Empleados` declarar un `CONSTRAINT` que tiene a `NumDepto` como llave foránea asociada a `NumDepto` de la tabla padre; que en este caso es `Departamentos`
2. Le asigne un nombre a dicha llave foránea llamada `fk_empleado_depto`